# How to work with multidimensional data in Halide

Tags: halide

I started working with Halide. I know it is explicitly an Image Processing framework, but is there a way to handle multidimensional array ( > 3D ) in it without doing any complex steps like Dimensionality Reduction or Separating the mathematical equations in lower dimensional spaces?

Thanks,
Karnajit

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I believe there is an absolute limitation of 4 dimensions for Buffer: https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/src/Buffer.cpp#L149

Then there seem to be further limitations depending on the target backend:
https://github.com/halide/Halide#limitations